# How would you pass through ">=" in the querystring?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, query-string

I would like to pass some operators through as querystring parameters so that I can convert them, along with a value into an SQL query. The idea would be to let the querystring parameters dictate wether the page returns search results where prices are equal to, greater than or equal to, greater than, less than or less than or equal to as follows:

```
=, >=, >, < and <=
```

I'm not sure what the best practise is for passing these operators through is, could anybody help me out? Would you pass through ascii codes or simply text like e, gte, gt, lt, lte and then convert them on results page that builds the query?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Use LINQ? That will do it for you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As user [Kon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22303/kon) said, use [`HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx). I've once written [a tiny little class to simplify working with query strings](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/SimpleQueryString.aspx) so that I do not have to call Server.UrlEncode.

As a side note, keep an eye on [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) aka Little Bobby Tables:

[image: Little Bobby Tables]
*([Source](http://xkcd.com/327/))*

Comment: @Uwe Keim: make this CW seeing as you've posted the most common quoted cartoon on SO...?

Comment: @gbn - please excuse my ignorance, what does "CW" stand for?

Comment: "Community Wiki": a checkbox underneath the text box where you type the answer

Comment: @gbn Done! Does it give me/the article/answer any benefits?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Uwe Keim! UrlEncode deffinately seems to be the way to go and it seems to work fine! Always trying to keep SQL Injection in mind, I guess the best way is to make sure the parameters are only equal to one of my 5 operators just before building the dynamic SQL?

Comment: @Sgt Yes, this would be how I do it, too. maybe `LIKE` would also be a valid operator.

Comment: I don't unstand what SQL injection has to do with this question.  That's a whole separate issue.  And if you're using (as you should) parameterized stored procedures or something like Entity Model Framework, you don't need to worry about SQL injection.

Comment: To me, as soon as I am building SQL queries by making string concatenation, I fear that I could do something wrong that is related to SQL injection.

Comment: How to defend against SQL injection here?

Answer (score 5):

[`Server.UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx)

Comment: could you show a code snippet containing some of the characters Sgt Beardy wants in his querystring?

Comment: Well, after doing Server.UrlEncode(">=") and adding this to my querystring before redirecting, I end up with this in the URL...

search.aspx?operator=%26gt%3d&value=5

I'm guessing I then use Server.UrlDecode on this querystring parameter when converting it for use in my SQL query? Then I need to check for SQL injection as Uwe mentioned in his answer. Thanks @Kon ! :)

Comment: Yes, you then call Server.UrlDecode to decode the parameter.  

I don't unstand what SQL injection has to do with this question.  That's a whole separate issue.  And if you're using (as you should) parameterized stored procedures or something like Entity Model Framework, you don't need to worry about SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

You can use  **eq, ne, gt, lt, ge, le, sa, eb, ap** like in the examples below

**ge** means **>=**

`GET [base]/subjects?grade=ge90`

**le** means **<=**
 `GET [base]/encounter?length=le20`

More information you can find on those websites:
https://www.hl7.org/fhir/stu3/search.html#number
https://www.hl7.org/fhir/stu3/search.html#prefix

Comment: this is a great sneaky, but still human readable solution. thanks! mucho kudos!

Answer (score 0):

URL encoding is definitely what you're looking for. Take a look at the Web.Utils namespace. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.util.httpencoder.aspx